# The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedItem' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list that is populating correctly on the page load but when I select a choice and submit it back with data from additional fields I am getting this error. Do I need to reset it back to the default value? In the below code "Industries" is a List of type SelectListItem.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.SelectedItem, Model.Industries)
     <br>
      //MORE CONTROLS 
     <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
 }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Calculate()
{
    ClassName DataStuff = new ClassName ();
    return View(new ClassName { Industries = DataStuff.IndustryList() 
});
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Calculate(ClassName  Items)
{
 ClassName CompleteItems = RetrieveData(Items);  
      // above additional calculations 
        return View(CompleteItems);
}
```

The model (with the relevant fields) is:

```
public class ClassName
{

    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Industries { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> IndustryList()
    {
       //populating the DDL
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of Industries. it should be of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: It is of type List<SelectListItem>.  Is that not correct for this circumstance?

Comment: Define it as  IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: Just did.  Same error.

Comment: Please share your model

Comment: Try renaming public string SelectedItem { get; set; } to public string MySelectedItem { get; set; }

Comment: How would changing the name of the variable change the functionality?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.
Define Industries as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` or

if you defined Industries as `List<SelectListItem>`
cast Industries to IEnumerable  like

`(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Industries`

2.In your model ,in place of `public string SelectedItem { get; set; }` use

`public string Industry{ get; set; }` and

in view update with new property `use @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.Industry, Model.Industries)`

Comment: That produces the same error :(

Comment: Is your SelectListItem of type System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem? check full name with namespace

Comment: Just checked. Yes it is.

Comment: try this public string Industry{ get; set; }

Comment: As opposed to a list?  It has to hold the DDL contents doesn't it?

Comment: in place of public string SelectedItem { get; set; } use public string Industry{ get; set; }  and in view use @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.Industry, Model.Industries)

Comment: That works!  In addition to the HTTPPOST method repopulating the DDL.  It was null going back from the submit

Comment: did you update with @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.Industry, Model.Industries) ?

Comment: Yes!  It's clearer that way.

Comment: whats the error you are getting now?

Comment: No it's working!  I said earlier that it works.

Comment: I'm new here so not enough to do that I think.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the question

Comment: @StephenMuecke clarify why its able to fix user's problem and he accepted answer?

Comment: You answer is completely wrong - OP model was just fine (and OP even stated your answer was not working - you just pressured them to accept your answer). Read the duplicate to understand what the problems was.

Comment: OP even identified their own problem -_In addition to the HTTPPOST method repopulating the DDL. It was null going back from the submit_ That is what the issue was - it had nothing to do with you answer